# How do I show intersecting points of three functions in 3D?

Tags: plotting

I'm trying to plot the following 3 functions:

- $f_1 = x^2 + y - 37 = 0$
- $f_2 = x - y^2 - 5 = 0$
- $f_3 = x + y - 3 - z = 0$

`Plot3D[{x^2 + y - 37, 
         x - y^2 - 5, 
         x + y + z - 3}, 
           {x, -10, 10}, 
           {y, -10, 10},
           {z, -10, 10}]`

but it gives me a error.  How do I fix this?  Also is there any way to show graphically where the 3 functions intersect, say with a red dot or something?

Thank you for the help in advance.

Comment: `ContourPlot3D[{x^2 + y - 37 == 0, x - y^2 - 5 == 0, 
  x + y + z - 3 == 0}, {x, -10, 10}, {y, -10, 10}, {z, -10, 10}]`

Comment: `Solve[{x^2 + y - 37 == 0, x - y^2 - 5 == 0, 
  x + y + z - 3 == 0}, Reals]` (or `NSolve`, if you prefer).

Comment: @corey979 More fool me, assumed complex solutions and missed out on second solution because I couldn't be bothered to add `Reals`, sloppy.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
s = Solve[{x^2 + y - 37 == 0, x - y^2 - 5 == 0, 
     x + y + z - 3 == 0}];
```

Two solutions.

```
Show[ContourPlot3D[{x^2 + y - 37 == 0, x - y^2 - 5 == 0, 
   x + y + z - 3 == 0}, {x, -10, 10}, {y, -10, 10}, {z, -10, 10}, 
  ContourStyle ->({#, Opacity[0.8]} &) /@ {Green, Yellow, Orange}], 
 Graphics3D[{Red, Sphere[{x, y, z} /. s[[#]]] & /@ {1, 2}}]]
```

[image]

Comment: thank you so much just one more question how do I put a coordinates?

Comment: @pkid58 Not sure I get your meaning. You can get the coordinates of the intersections with `s[[1]]` and `s[[2]]`. If you want to add the coordinates to the plot look up `Text[]`

Comment: I meant like how do i label the x axis y axis and z axis sorry for the confusion

Comment: See `AxesLabel`